# FFTW linking in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, fftw

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on a 64-bit operating system.  I'm trying to use FFTW in a program, but having problems getting the libraries to link.

I downloaded the 64-bit package from the FFTW Windows page.  I followed these steps:

- `lib /machine:x64 /def:libfftw3-3.def`
- `lib /machine:x64 /def:libfftw3f-3.def`
- `lib /machine:x64 /def:libfftw3l-3.def`

This created the .exp and .lib files.

I added the path with all of the files in:

> Properties -> Debugging -> Environment
>   Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories
>   Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories
>   Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories

I added the .lib files to Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

I added the following lines to the top of my code:

```
#define FFTW_DLL
#include <fftw3.h>
```

then I put the sample code from the FFTW tutorial into my code, like so:

```
fftw_complex *in; 
fftw_complex *out;

fftw_plan p;

in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*L);
out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*L);
p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(L, in, out,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE); 

fftw_execute(p);
fftw_destroy_plan(p);
fftw_free(in);
fftw_free(out);
```

When I then try to build my application, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_execute referenced in function _wmain C:\EEG_Hardware\source\dspApp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   1   1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_plan_dft_1d referenced in function _wmain C:\EEG_Hardware\source\dspApp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   1   1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_destroy_plan referenced in function _wmain    C:\EEG_Hardware\source\dspApp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   1   1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_malloc referenced in function _wmain  C:\EEG_Hardware\source\dspApp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   1   1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fftw_free referenced in function _wmain    C:\EEG_Hardware\source\dspApp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.obj   1   1   ConsoleApplication1
Error   6   error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals   C:\EEG_Hardware\source\dspApp\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe ConsoleApplication1
```

I've been searching through this site, trying any solution I can find, but so far no luck.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I also used your procedure, but it didn't fully worked also for me.

I modified the procedure by copying, before the generation of the .exp and .lib files, the files

```
msobj100.dll
mspdb100.dll
mspdbcore.dll
mspdbsrv.exe
```

you can find at the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE directory.

Also, I finally copied the three .dll files into the folder of your project where .vcxproj and .vcxproj.filters are located.